# R shiny - rendering multiple output for the same analysis

Tags: r, output, render, shiny, shiny-server

If I have a rather time consuming analysis, let's say fitting a model to some data set. I want to display all the output of the model fitting, say there will be renderPlot(), renderTable(), renderText(), etc. How do I render all of them with the model running only once? My current code looks like the following:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {  

output$twang_diagplot <- renderPlot({

if(is.null(data())|input$twang_x=='.'|input$twang_y=='.') return(NULL)

else{
  formula <- paste(input$twang_y, "~",paste(input$twang_x,collapse='+')) 

  ps_fit <- ps(as.formula(formula),data=workdata(),verbose=FALSE)

  plot(ps_fit)   
}
})

output$twang_summary <- renderPrint({

if(is.null(data())|input$twang_x=='.'|input$twang_y=='.') return(NULL)

else{
  formula <- paste(input$twang_y, "~",paste(input$twang_x,collapse='+')) 

  ps_fit <- ps(as.formula(formula),data=workdata(),verbose=FALSE)

  ps_balance <- bal.table(ps_fit)

  print(ps_balance)   
} 
})
})
```

In the above example, I had to call the ps() function twice to generate plot and summary separately. This is very inefficient. I know there should be a function such as reactive() or observe() that I could use to wrap the two render functions together after calling the ps() function but I'm not sure how to use it. 
Would appreciate your help!
regards

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {  
getPsFit <- reactive({
formula <- paste(input$twang_y, "~",paste(input$twang_x,collapse='+'))
ps_fit <- ps(as.formula(formula),data=workdata(),verbose=FALSE)
ps_fit
})
output$twang_diagplot <- renderPlot({
if(is.null(data())|input$twang_x=='.'|input$twang_y=='.') return(NULL)

else{
ps_fit <- getPsFit()
plot(ps_fit)   
}
})

output$twang_summary <- renderPrint({

if(is.null(data())|input$twang_x=='.'|input$twang_y=='.') return(NULL)

else{
ps_fit <- getPsFit()

ps_balance <- bal.table(ps_fit)

print(ps_balance)   
} 
})
})
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the two calls to `ps()` are using different arguments, so I'm not sure you can use a reactive in this case that will only be called once because `ps` would have to be called twice, I don't see a way around that...

PS. your code could benefit from some more spacing to make it a lot more readable :)

**edit after your comment:**
Have you read the [Shiny tutorial, specifically the section of reactive expressions?](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/)
Something like this should work

```
getPsFit <- reactive({
    formula <- paste(input$twang_y, "~",paste(input$twang_x,collapse='+'))
    ps_fit <- ps(as.formula(formula),data=workdata(),verbose=FALSE)
    ps_fit
})
```

now just replace your two lines of code in both else statements with `ps_fit <- getPsFit()`

Comment: thanks for your reply! In fact my two ps() could use the same arguments. In that case how could I use the reactive() to wrap the two render outputs?

Comment: Hi daattali,
can you have a look at the above code? is it something like this? But seems that the getPsFit() function is still called twice?
PS I did read the tutorial but can't seem to make it work so I think maybe I'm not doing it in the right way..

Comment: `getPsFit` will run every time one of its dependencies changes.  It has two dependencies (`input$twang_x` and `input$twang_y`) so it's possible that it's getting called twice, once for each input change. If that's the problem, that can be fixed with an `actionButton`

Comment: reactivity is a little hard to grasp at first, it can be confusing, if you're new to it I suggest looking at lots of Shiny app examples to try to understand it

Comment: Indeed a little confusing! Even if the two dependencies don't change, isn't it true that getPsFit is called when I renderPlot and then called again when I renderPrint?

Comment: Sure, it's called, but the code inside doesn't get run.  Re-read the link I posted, to Shiny's official tutorial on reactive expression. It explains it right there. "Reactive expressions are a bit smarter than regular R functions. They cache their values and know when their values have become outdated. What does this mean? The first time that you run a reactive expression, the expression will save its result in your computer’s memory. The next time you call the reactive expression, it can return this saved result without doing any computation (which will make your app faster)."

Comment: You can also easily just test this all out, just put a print statement inside `getPsFit` and see when it gets executed

Comment: brilliant! indeed very smart! thanks a lot daattali! Now it's time for me to rewrite all my code